# How to fill a no-value colum with a default value in result set (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query like follows:

```
SELECT table1.time, table1.co, table2.co_ro
FROM(
SELECT p1.time, SUM(p1.kpi_0) AS co
FROM hourly_history p1
WHERE p1.type_id=3
GROUP BY p1.time) AS table1,(
SELECT p2.time, SUM(p2.kpi_0) AS co_ro
FROM hourly_history p2
WHERE p2.type_id=5
GROUP BY p2.time) AS table2
WHERE table1.time=table2.time
```

If data exist for type_id=3 and does not exist for type_id=5 for a specific time value (let's say 12-10-2011 12:00:00), row of that time doesn't exist in result set as expected.

I need a query that returns the row for that specific time even no data exist for type_id=5. How can I write such a query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the different types of joins http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This concept should work (although I have not tested these queries):

```
SELECT t1, sum(co), sum(co_ro)
FROM
(
  (
    SELECT p1.time AS t1, SUM(p1.kpi_0) AS co, 0 AS co_ro
    FROM hourly_history p1
    WHERE p1.type_id=3
    GROUP BY p1.time
  )

  UNION ALL

  (
    SELECT p2.time AS t1, 0 AS co, SUM(p2.kpi_0) AS co_ro
    FROM hourly_history p2
    WHERE p2.type_id=5
    GROUP BY p2.time
  )
)

GROUP BY t1;
```

This should be even simpler:

```
SELECT t1, sum(co), sum(co_ro)
FROM
(
  (
    SELECT p1.time AS t1, p1.kpi_0 AS co, 0 AS co_ro
    FROM hourly_history p1
    WHERE p1.type_id=3
  )

  UNION ALL

  (
    SELECT p2.time AS t1, 0 AS co, p2.kpi_0 AS co_ro
    FROM hourly_history p2
    WHERE p2.type_id=5
  )
)

GROUP BY t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic way to do this is to create a table with all the times that should exist, and then left join against that. Then your missing values become nulls, which you can use `COALESCE` to fill with defaults.

The table with the times doesn't have to be a base table. It can be built by joining together a days, hours, and minutes table, either as a view or as part of the query.

Though, in your example query, you *might* get what you want just by switching from an inner join to a left join. MySQL doesn't do full outer join, unfortunately.